# Mountain Lion Finder Memory Issues

Tags: macos, memory, finder, osx-mountain-lion, memory-usage

Since upgrading to Mountain Lion, I've been noticing that the Finder has a fondness of gobbling up multiple gigabytes of real memory. Although a quick relaunch gets it back down to <100 MB, this doesn't seem to be how it's intended to be used.

Is there any way to introspect why it's using so much memory (e.g. with the developer tools), and what I may be doing wrong (or have installed) that can address this?

**Update:** I noticed that it starts ballooning immediately after an “All My Files” window is opened. However, I'm fairly certain it has also reached the multi-GB level in instances where I haven't opened “All My Files”.

Comment: What kind of applications do you have that modify Finder behavior in some way? (Think Dropbox, Google Drive for displaying icons, add-ons like TotalFinder, etc)

Comment: Dropbox, Google Drive, and SkyDrive. Just tried quitting all three and relaunching the Finder; no effect.

Comment: I'm farily certain that even when you quit Dropbox or similar, they will leave some kind of code in Finder. If it's not too much of a hassle you could try removing the `/Library/DropboxHelperTools` and possibly trying on another user account if the issue persists. By the way, my Mac starts crapping out as well when I click "All My Files", but my Finder is using around 100 MB real memory, constantly.

Comment: Tried removing that, quitting all of them and removed them from Login Items. No dice.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but from what I can tell, it really does seem `mds`-related. Though I'm not sure how to verify this assumption, or what to do about it.

Comment: If it's `mds` you could try disabling Spotlight and testing: `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist` (reenable with `load` instead of `unload`)

Comment: That's what I was thinking. ;-/ I'm currently trying out that and some other stuff in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65486/how-to-fix-slow-spotlight-and-time-machine-after-upgrading-to-10-7-5

Comment: Ran through what you mentioned, plus the other stuff in that Ask Different post, and it's now fixed. Your help has been much appreciated.

Comment: Although my original question was oriented towards introspecting into what it is that the Finder is using so much memory for (I've used Windows and Linux tools to do this), I'm no longer in need of a solution. _Perhaps this question is too focused on what should be a larger stand-alone question, and should be closed._

Comment: If you have a concrete solution, you can post it as an answer below. Just explain what you did and how you solved it. This way you'll help others with the same problem. Of course we can close this question as well, just let me know.

Comment: I really should've searched/posted on Ask Different in the first place. My apologies. Let's close this one.

Comment: No worries. Questions about OS X are equally on topic here, so feel free to post them here or on Ask Different, and if they don't receive enough attention we can always migrate them.

Comment: I had the same issue with Macbook Pro retina, Mountain Lion. mds + Finder where consuming all memory and 300% of CPU, disabling mds helped.